# SAS 9.3 rsubmit email

Tags: sas

I’ve recently been upgraded from SAS 9.2 (32-bit) to SAS 9.3 (64-bit) with Office 2010 (32-bit).

Almost everything seems to work fine, however I can’t get SAS to send emails without a remote submit!

If I submit locally, I get the message “ERROR: Undetermined I/O failure“ and a pop up from Excel stating “Either there is no default mail client or the current mail client cannot fulfill the messaging request. Please run Microsoft Outlook and set it as the default mail client.”

My outlook is the default mail client!

Does anyone know why this is?

If I do remote submit, I then I can’t attach files stored on my desktop or shared drives!

Sample of my code is below:

```
rsubmit;
filename outmail email
subject="Cars (secure)"
TO= ("email")
CC= ("email")
ATTACH= "C:\\Book1.xlsx";
DATA _NULL_;
FILE outmail;
PUT "Hello All,";
PUT " ";
PUT "Please find attached the Cars file.";
PUT " ";
RUN;
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the local configuration.  There are three different approaches you can take:

1 - Click Start / Control Panel / Programs / Programs and Features / Microsoft Office 2010 / Change / Repair / Continue. Now follow the repair process.

2 - Click Start / Type & select "Default Programs" - follow the on-screen instructions to set Outlook as the default.

3 - Browse to the location below, and delete MSMAPI32.DLL:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\MSMAPI\1033

The file will be recreated once Outlook 2010 relaunches.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, i have already tried these steps without success. However i tried again and still no luck.